# Getting my footer div color to go vertical in responsive design. bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, footer

I am trying to get my footer, which has a grey color to show this color all the way to the bottom in my responsive design. It goes all the way across the page when in PC view mode, when I take it to the mobile size, the box only shows for half of the footer and then cuts off. I am not sure why it's not working for me.

Thanks ahead of time for taking a look.

HTML:

```
div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h3 class="footertext">About Us:</h3>
            <br>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <center>
                  <img src="http://oi60.tinypic.com/w8lycl.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="the-brains">
                  <br>
                  <h4 class="footertext">Sitemap info 1</h4>
                  <p class="footertext">here is some site map info<br>
                </center>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <center>
                  <img src="http://oi60.tinypic.com/2z7enpc.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="...">
                  <br>
                  <h4 class="footertext">Sitemap info 2</h4>
                  <p class="footertext">here is some more site map info<br>
                </center>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <center>
                  <img src="http://oi61.tinypic.com/307n6ux.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="...">
                  <br>
                  <h4 class="footertext">sitemap info 3</h4>
                  <p class="footertext">This is some more of it.<br>
                </center>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <p><center><a href="#">Contact Stuff Here</a> <p class="footertext">Copyright 2014</p></center></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

CSS:

#footer {
  position: absolute;

  bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 280px;
background-color:#B6B6B4;
    /*
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `col-md-4` classes for your grid, causing each column take a full row in mobile view and your footer is not going all the way to the bottom of page because of its fixed height (`280px`).
Try using `col-xs-4` for x-small devices and appropriate classes for other windows sizes. 
This can be achieved by doing something like `<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">Content</div>` which means this columns will use 4 grids in desktop view and 6 grids in mobile viewport.


More documentation can be found [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), under 'Grid options' section.

By the way, `<center>` tag is obsolete, I would recommend you to use Bootstrap's `text-center` CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend posting your code in jsfiddle for easier debugging: http://jsfiddle.net/r7mTc/

In jsfiddle above you will see that content of the footer is way higher than the footer itself and stick out of it.

Now look here: http://jsfiddle.net/r7mTc/1/ I just deleted height line in CSS ;)

I also see few other problems in your code:

1. > `<p><center><a href="#">Contact Stuff Here</a> <p
   >   class="footertext">Copyright 2014</p></center></p>`

   Tag `p` can contain only inline elements like `span` or `img`, so there shouldn't be nested `p` tags.
2. > `<p class="footertext">here is some more site map info<br>`

   Tag `p` should always has be closed, so you should add `</p>` after `<br>`
3. `<center>` tag is deprecated. Better practise is to use CSS for that - for example `text-align:center` for inline elements or `margin:auto` for blocks.